# 16.04 LTS mouse lag if

Tags: drivers, nvidia, mouse, games

Running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with a 6GB GTX 1060 Nvidia card with 32 gigs of RAM.  When I launch a game (Stellaris), I get weird mouse lag.  When I leave the game, the mouse lag persists.  When I reboot the machine, the mouse lag seems to end. I ma using the proprietary 384.90 Nvidia Driver.

I should also point out I am using dual monitors, in case that seems to be related.  I'm guessing it is not.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the memory issue on the CPU side, you can open the system monitor to see if you have enough **swap file** in the resources tag, when the mouse lag happens.

Also I would suggest to use 17.10 for GTX Nvidia card, since previous I tried to use GTX with 16.04.3 and mouse/keyboard lags after the system runs for a while. Then I switch to 17.10 then everything works out fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my Dell XPS 9560 and it was because I had disabled the crytswap in Ubuntu 17.10 in order to get the nvidia drivers working.

I have just added a normal swapfile back to the system at the same size as my RAM (16GB) and it works fine now